# Can we use "the" (definite article) with nouns to refer to a group of that name?

Tags: grammar, nouns, adjectives, definite-articles

Can we use "the" (definite article) with nouns to refer to a group of that name?

For example, on learnenglish.britishcouncil.org and [this article](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/determiners-and-quantifiers/definite-article) said:

> to say something about all the things referred to by a noun:
>
> - The wolf is not really a dangerous animal (= Wolves are not really dangerous animals)
> - The kangaroo is found only in Australia (= Kangaroos are found only in Australia)
> - The heart pumps blood around the body. (= Hearts pump blood around bodies)

Is that really right?

Because I only saw in that site and I know that when "the" comes before adjectives it refers to a group of people.

Comment: It certainly is right but I cannot explain why. It means "the class of things in which an individual member is known as..." As the examples indicate, it seems to suggest a didactic function. I can't imagine ever saying such a sentence unless I were speaking at a lecture.

Comment: @Nigel J Yes, it was a good question. When first asked.